# Best way to play poker online for playchips

Tags: online

I got hooked to holdem poker on fulltiltpoker.com a few years back. They were shutdown for some financial irregularities. Since then I've been playing on facebook with zynga poker but it's not that much fun, I also played Governor of Poker but it's AI isn't all that good.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a poker client or website that offers the games which are similar to fulltilt. Just to be clear I'm not into gambling and will be playing only for play chips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all legitimate sites offer some kind of play-chip option within their gaming platform. I know [Pokerstars.com](http://www.pokerstars.com) has one, and it gets a lot of traffic. Using software from sites that offer both play money and real money games will often have superior software functionality so I'd suggest going down that route.

Also, there is another question that may be of use to you [here](https://poker.stackexchange.com/q/3/88).

Comment: +1 for pokerstars

Answer (score 2):

Toby's answer of Pokerstars.com is a good option if you are outside of the United States. If you are in the US, you can't currently play real money games on Pokerstars for reasons similar to the reasons that FullTilt was shut down. You can still play most free/play-money games there. But should you desire to move to real money play, it is not an option. Additionally, you cannot play in freeroll tournaments.

Other good options for players in the US include [Lock Poker](http://rakeback.grinderschool.com/lock-poker) and [Black Chip Poker](http://rakeback.grinderschool.com/black-chip-poker). Both of these sites offer play money games, AND they allow you to play in freerolls or to move to real money games if you ever decide that you would like to do so.

Comment: I believe that, if you're in the US, you can't play on PokerStars with real money... the question is about virtual money... or am I missing something ?

Comment: I believe that Pokerstars does not let US players create an account at all. I assume that means virtual money play is out too. Will try...

Comment: You're right - you can play for play money. Though you can't do freerolls. I'll update accordingly.

Comment: Aha. Would've tested myself, but I don't live in the US. +1 :) .